# Domain of $x^y$

Tags: functions

What is the exact domain of $f(x,y)=x^y$ ?

Is it $D= ( \mathbb{R^{-}} \times \mathbb{Z}) \cup ( \{0\} \times \mathbb{R-\{0\}}) \cup( \mathbb{R^+} \times \mathbb{R})$ ?

Comment: What is the question mark for?

Comment: I would know in general what is the maximum domain of $x^y$.

Comment: I got that.  I was referring to the question mark within the second line, not the one at the end of the first line.  Without that, it looks good.

Comment: @badjohn, the second line begins "Is it..." so the question mark at the end is appropriate.

Comment: To the OP: you seem to be allowing $(0,-1)$ in the domain. But $0^{-1}$ is not defined.

Comment: Maybe it is a quirk of my tablet which does not always show mathjax correctly but I see the question mark within the last set.of parentheses and not at the end which would make sense,

Comment: @badjohn, ah, it must be a quirk of your tablet. It looks fine on my laptop.

Comment: My apologies to the OP.  Please disregard my comments.

Comment: Can you allow for complex numbers.

Comment: Depends on how $x^y$ was defined.  Some (most?) texts would allow if $r$ is rational and $r = \frac ab; a,b\in \mathbb Z$ and $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ and $b > 0$ then $x^r = \sqrt[b]{x^a}$ which case if $x < 0$ and $r = \frac ab; a$ is even, we'd have $(x,r)$ in the domain.  So not merely $\mathbb R_-\times \mathbb Z$ but $\mathbb R_- \times X$, $X = \{\frac {2a}b|a,b\in \mathbb Z; \gcd(2a,b)=1\}\subset \mathbb Q$ is also in the domain.

Comment: ...argh... not quite.  $X =\{\frac ab|a,b\in \mathbb Z; \gcd(a,b) = 1; b>0; b\text{ is not even}\}$.

Comment: @badjohn Don't worry :)

Comment: @fleadblood only real. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @BarryCipra Good observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also $f(-\sqrt 2,\dfrac{1}{3})$ is valid but not included by the domain mentioned up in the question. Let's define $$\forall x\in\Bbb R^{-},p,q\in\Bbb Z , q>0 \qquad , \qquad x^{\frac{p}{q}}=(x^p)^{\frac{1}{q}}\qquad , \qquad \gcd(p,q)=1$$then this power operation means only if $$1)\quad \text{p is even}\\2) \quad \text{both p and q are odd}$$then the correct domain is $$D= ( \mathbb{R_{-}} \times \mathbb{A}) \cup ( \{0\} \times \mathbb{R^+}) \cup( \mathbb{R_+} \times \mathbb{R})$$where$$\Bbb A=\{x\in\Bbb Q|x=\dfrac{p}{q},\quad\text{p(q+1) is even and p and q are coprime}\}$$

Comment: "Also f(2–√,13) is valid but not included by the domain"  Yes, it is.  $\sqrt 2, \frac 13 \in \mathbb R_+\times \mathbb R \subset$ of the domain listed.

Comment: Sorry I meant $f(-\sqrt 2,\dfrac{1}{3})$   :)

Comment: @MostafaAyaz In up comment Barry Cipra noted that $0^{-1}$ is not defined. What do you think about that?

Comment: Thank you....I included that either